# Why is torbrowser-launcher trying to use inotify for my IME?

Tags: fcitx, inotify, tor-browser

```
torbrowser-launcher
```

readout suddenly included:

```
inotify_add_watch(~/.config/fcitx/dbus) failed: (Permission denied)
```

I checked another machine and it's not there.

This has never appeared before.

Any ideas on what that is and how I can fix it?

Also, I was reading online, trying to research and answer someone's question, just before this and there was a NoScript popup request which I blocked. It was when I restarted that this inotify line first appeared.

Not sure if the two are connected.

```
sudo apt-get purge fcitx
```

first yielded a strange message about dpkg being interrupted. I had to run

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

After purging fcitx and all other associated files, the inotify message was not there in the readout.
However, reinstalling fcitx brought it right back.

I have other Impish machines with fcitx installed and this is the only one with this strange inotify message.

```
chown
```

was able to remove the inotify permission denied message, but I still want to know:

1. Is it normal for torbrowser-launcher to initiate inotify_add_watch for my IME?
2. What is the purpose of inotify_add_watch?

Comment: I launched the browser from a terminal emulator and that "appeared" in the readout as it was launching.

Usually, it displays the browser version and a link to the project page... I just don't remember seeing inotify before?

Comment: torbrowser-launcher

Comment: @YQ002lc2 Please edit your question and add this relevant information to it instead of in the comments. New readers won't necessarily need the comments.

Comment: "Inotify isn't even installed on my machine." inotify is provided by the kernel, what you're talking about is just the command line tool to access it. You might not be seeing this message on other systems because there's no error on them. Maybe look into why this permission is being denied in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So is it normal for inotify_add_watch to be initiated by torbrowser-launcher & I'm only seeing this because the permission is being denied?